# EXISTS vs IN - which one is better in MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

I'm testing the two different SQL approaches (EXISTS vs IN) on both MySQL 5.7 & 5.5 from a performance perspective.
As a side note about the test, both database are on the same machine, where I activated only one of them for each test. Each of them has 4GB of memory allocated to them. I restarted the database before every test to make sure there is no caching done (at least not at the database level).

I saw many questions here on StackOverflow, where a transformation from IN to EXISTS was helpful in terms of performance. In most threads, this was the case for older MySQL versions (ver < 5.6). So my first goal was to test this theory (EXISTS is better than IN for older MySQL versions).

Also, I've been reading that IN might have been improved in newer MySQL versions, so I wanted to see that in person.

Therefore, to better understand which one is preferable for my future queries, I ran the following test:

Defining the constant quantity:

```
SET @quantity = 50;
```

**EXISTS query:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    c.c_first_name, c.c_birth_country
FROM
    customer c
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT 
            1
        FROM
            store_sales ss
        WHERE
            ss.ss_quantity > @quantity
                AND ss.ss_customer_sk = c.c_customer_sk)
ORDER BY c.c_first_name DESC , c.c_birth_country DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

**The equivalent IN query:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    c.c_first_name, c.c_birth_country
FROM
    customer c
WHERE
    c.c_customer_sk IN (SELECT 
            ss.ss_customer_sk
        FROM
            store_sales ss
        WHERE
            ss.ss_quantity > @quantity)
ORDER BY c.c_first_name DESC , c.c_birth_country DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

**The results:**

- MySQL 5.5 - EXISTS - 53 seconds
- MySQL 5.5 - IN     - 48 seconds
- MySQL 5.7 - EXISTS - 46 seconds
- MySQL 5.7 - IN     - 4  seconds

As you can see, the results were kind of surprising:

1. From some reason the EXISTS alternative performed worse than the IN alternative with MySQL 5.5.
2. For MySQL 5.7, IN seems to perform significantly better than EXISTS, even though the EXPLAIN of the EXISTS alternative "looks better" than the IN alternative (see EXPLAIN outputs below).

Can you please share your thoughts?

When you're approaching to write a new query, how do you choose between IN and EXISTS? How would you guide your team? We can try them both every time, but it sounds kind of ridicules and can waste a lot of time when writing complex queries.. there should be some guideline to when each of them is better, for both MySQL < 5.6 and MySQL > 5.6.

Any documentation from MySQL that I'm missing?

Just to close the loop with all the relevant table and explain information -

**Table creation scripts with the indexes** (you might see many non useful or redundant indexes here as well, but please ignore them as this is a test environment):

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
   `c_customer_sk` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `c_customer_id` char(16) NOT NULL,
   `c_current_cdemo_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_current_hdemo_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_current_addr_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_first_shipto_date_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_first_sales_date_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_salutation` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_first_name` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_last_name` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_preferred_cust_flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_birth_day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_birth_month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_birth_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_birth_country` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_login` char(13) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_email_address` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `c_last_review_date` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`c_customer_sk`),
   KEY `c_fsd2` (`c_first_shipto_date_sk`),
   KEY `c_fsd` (`c_first_sales_date_sk`),
   KEY `c_hd` (`c_current_hdemo_sk`),
   KEY `c_cd` (`c_current_cdemo_sk`),
   KEY `c_a` (`c_current_addr_sk`),
   KEY `customer_index_1` (`c_first_name`,`c_birth_country`),
   CONSTRAINT `c_a` FOREIGN KEY (`c_current_addr_sk`) REFERENCES `customer_address` (`ca_address_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `c_cd` FOREIGN KEY (`c_current_cdemo_sk`) REFERENCES `customer_demographics` (`cd_demo_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `c_fsd` FOREIGN KEY (`c_first_sales_date_sk`) REFERENCES `date_dim` (`d_date_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `c_fsd2` FOREIGN KEY (`c_first_shipto_date_sk`) REFERENCES `date_dim` (`d_date_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `c_hd` FOREIGN KEY (`c_current_hdemo_sk`) REFERENCES `household_demographics` (`hd_demo_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `store_sales` (
   `ss_sold_date_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_sold_time_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_item_sk` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ss_customer_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_cdemo_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_hdemo_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_addr_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_store_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_promo_sk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_ticket_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ss_quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_wholesale_cost` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_list_price` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_sales_price` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_ext_discount_amt` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_ext_sales_price` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_ext_wholesale_cost` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_ext_list_price` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_ext_tax` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_coupon_amt` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_net_paid` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_net_paid_inc_tax` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ss_net_profit` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ss_item_sk`,`ss_ticket_number`),
   KEY `ss_s` (`ss_store_sk`),
   KEY `ss_t` (`ss_sold_time_sk`),
   KEY `ss_d` (`ss_sold_date_sk`),
   KEY `ss_p` (`ss_promo_sk`),
   KEY `ss_hd` (`ss_hdemo_sk`),
   KEY `ss_c` (`ss_customer_sk`),
   KEY `ss_cd` (`ss_cdemo_sk`),
   KEY `ss_a` (`ss_addr_sk`),
   KEY `store_sales_index_1` (`ss_quantity`,`ss_customer_sk`),
   KEY `store_sales_idx_sk_price` (`ss_item_sk`,`ss_sales_price`),
   KEY `store_sales_idx_price_sk` (`ss_sales_price`,`ss_item_sk`),
   CONSTRAINT `ss_a` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_addr_sk`) REFERENCES `customer_address` (`ca_address_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_c` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_customer_sk`) REFERENCES `customer` (`c_customer_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_cd` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_cdemo_sk`) REFERENCES `customer_demographics` (`cd_demo_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_d` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_sold_date_sk`) REFERENCES `date_dim` (`d_date_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_hd` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_hdemo_sk`) REFERENCES `household_demographics` (`hd_demo_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_i` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_item_sk`) REFERENCES `item` (`i_item_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_p` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_promo_sk`) REFERENCES `promotion` (`p_promo_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_s` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_store_sk`) REFERENCES `store` (`s_store_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `ss_t` FOREIGN KEY (`ss_sold_time_sk`) REFERENCES `time_dim` (`t_time_sk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Explain - MySQL 5.7 - EXISTS alternative -**

```
1   PRIMARY c       index       customer_index_1    124     1000    100.00  Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ss      ref ss_c,store_sales_index_1    ss_c    5   tpcds.c.c_customer_sk   32  50.00   Using where
```

**Explain - MySQL 5.7 - IN alternative -**

```
1   SIMPLE  ss      range   ss_c,store_sales_index_1    store_sales_index_1 5       1395022 100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary
1   SIMPLE  c       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tpcds.ss.ss_customer_sk 1   100.00  End temporary
```

**Explain - MySQL 5.5 - EXISTS alternative -**

```
1   PRIMARY c   index       customer_index_1    124     1000    Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ss  ref ss_c,store_sales_index_1    ss_c    5   tpcds.c.c_customer_sk   14  Using where
```

**Explain - MySQL 5.5 - IN alternative -**

```
1   PRIMARY c   index       customer_index_1    124     1000    Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ss  index_subquery  ss_c,store_sales_index_1    ss_c    5   func    14  Using where
```

Comment: Note:there are subtle semantic differences (wrt handling NULLs) between IN and EXISTS. Choose the *correct* one instead of the *fastest*.

Comment: @wildplasser, thanks. In this specific question and test I'm ignoring that difference, as in many cases NULLs are irrelevant.

Comment: In term of performance can you try with an INNER JOIN ? I have always heard it's better.

Comment: @DanielE. the problem with inner joins is that in many cases it will return different results, because of the Cartesian nature of the join. Therefore, it will require some kind of trick such as applying DISTINCT to reduce the amount of results back (which will probably slow down the query). Therefore, in this test, I'm focusing on IN vs EXISTS, and maybe in the future I'll expand the test to inner joins as well.

Comment: " SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    c.c_first_name, c.c_birth_country
FROM
    customer c
INNER JOIN  (SELECT 
            ss.ss_customer_sk
        FROM
            store_sales ss
        WHERE
            ss.ss_quantity > @quantity) t ON t.ss_customer_sk = c.c_customer_sk
ORDER BY c.c_first_name DESC , c.c_birth_country DESC  "
Will return a different result ?

Comment: @DanielE. yes, because there are cases where one customer has several records in store_sales, so in the alternative you suggested, the same customer will be returned more than once because it matched several records with different quantities in store_sales. Anyways, I would appreciate if we could please focus on the original question though (which was EXISTS vs IN).

Answer (score 3):

There is no ultimate truth to that question. If `in` would always perform worse than `exists`, the first trivial step the optimizer could take would be to simply rewrite every `in` to `exists`.

`in` allows the optimizer to utilize [several different execution paths](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html) that you cannot do for general `exists` subquerys. It especially can execute `in` as `exists` (but not vice-versa). So if you want to have a general guideline, you could use `in` wherever possible, as it can trivially be rewritten to `exists`, leaving you the option (and the compiler) to do it either way. If tests show that MySQL took a wrong path, you may simply switch to `exists`, forcing the optimizer to do the same.

If the optimizer chooses to take one of those newly available execution plans, they might turn out to be faster - or not. That is true for many decisions the optimizer makes: it basically guesses based on some limited information it has about your data, and might guess incorrectly. A direct approach to tell the optimizer to explore some different path is to utilize [Optimizer Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html). Changing the query a bit (e.g. switching `in` to `exists`) can make the optimizer choose a different execution plan too (e.g. because others are not available anymore), so you may think of it as an indirect hint, although it is less controllable than actual hints.

These might turn out to give you a faster result - or, for the same reason, the opposite. It will usually depend on your actual data and situation. You are correct to simply test it for your specific situation and choose the one that's faster. But keep in mind that the situation can change (if your data distribution changes), so you may need to retest and potentially rewrite your query at some point.

But it will not be generally applicable - as you already realized, for your specific situation, your assumption that *"EXISTS is better than IN for older MySQL versions"* does not hold, while it seems to do so for most of the questions you looked at (which may or may not be a biased selection).

After that general introduction (you wanted to hear some thoughts, so you got some):

The reason your `in` for 5.7 performs so well is because MySQL found, amongst the possible execution plans, a way that works very well for your specific data distribution.

Assume you have only 1 customer with `ss_quantity > @quantity`. Since you have an index on `ss_quantity`, the fastest answer to your query is to simply use this index, look up the customer with that quantity and you are done. The more customer you have with that quantity-value, the less effective this gets. E.g. assume every customer fulfills the quantity condition, then an index that supports your `order by` (and thus the `limit`) is preferable - which is what MySQL 5.5 decided to do by choosing an execution plan plan that utilizes the index `customer_index_1`.

Changing `exists` to `in` made MySQL find that path. The optimizer got a lot better between 5.5. and 5.7., so this is more than just random luck. But if your data distribution would be beyond the tipping point and MySQL would have still took that path, it would become slower. There will be a magic number of customers where you reach the break even point. You are obviously on the good side side of that point.

A way to test this would be to set `@quantity` to a lower value. You will probably find a value where `in` will be executed like `exists`, and maybe even a value where `exists` is faster than `in`. Another factor is the value of `limit`. `limit 1` should (assuming your query returns more then a handful of rows) be executed like `exists` currently is, and so you will probably find some parameters for quantity and limit where `in` will be slower than `exists`. If MySQL does change the execution plan for `in` to be similar to `exists`, there will be some value for limit where it doesn't (we know that at least for the value `1000`). You may find a value where `in` is again slower than `exists`.

But to stretch the point again: it is not generally applicable. The values will depepend on your data, and the situation might change with it. If you e.g. get more and more customers, a limit of 1000 might get less and less relevant and you might reach the tipping point in the future where `in` is gets worse than `exists` (without MySQL realizing it), and might have to change your query.

Comment: thank you for your reply, very much appreciated. I can't see though why the IN query in MySQL 5.7 performs better, as there are many customers with that quantity (not only 1 / few). Also, more importantly, I'm not sure I understand how would you approach to such scenarios in the future - would you just test both options for each query? What if you have several IN / EXISTS subqueries in one query? It becomes a serious hassle to just test all options every time. I hoped to have some idea on specific factors (a,b,c) which are optimal for IN and (d,e,f) which are optimal for EXISTS...

Comment: Well, the execution plan MySQL chose is the one that uses the "1"-scenario (you can see it uses the `store_sales_index_1`-index to retrieve the list of customers: it "starts with ss and joins 1 customer from c into it"). It does not matter how many there are exactly, it turned out to be faster, the "1" was just to make it clear why it can be faster. At some number of customers, the additional filesort will slow it down, I do not know what that number is in your specific case (so e.g. test it with quantity 0).

Comment: As I tried to make it clear (which I obviously didn't, I might rewrite that part): the prefered method is to use "in", giving MySQL the option to decide to execute it as "exists". There is no general rule when it is not (as then, MySQL could just use this rule itself in the optimizer phase and you again can use "in"). In some situations, MySQL will choose wrong. You can then try to use "exists", it may or may not help. Same for hints like e.g. "force index" - ideally, MySQL finds it itself, sometimes it doesn't. But if you "force index" (or "exists"), it will not adept if your data changes.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a fair comparison?

`EXISTS` is a "semi-join" -- that is, it performs a join-like lookup, but stops when a single row is found.

`IN` implies finding all the rows.  Did your `IN` test have at least a hundred values in the `SELECT` in the `IN`?

The speed of both `EXISTS` and `IN` depend on what index(es) are available.  For example, `WHERE ss.ss_quantity > @quantity AND ss.ss_customer_sk = c.c_customer_sk)` needs `INDEX(ss_customer_sk, ss_quantity)` *in that order*.  Without any index, the speed of `EXISTS` depends on where in the table the first matching row is found!  If it is at the end, it will be as slow as `IN`!  Since you have a less-good index (the opposite order), the efficiency of `EXISTS` depends on some distributions that are not visible in this thread.

`ORDER BY c.c_first_name DESC , c.c_birth_country DESC LIMIT 1000;` -- If you do not have `INDEX(c_first_name, c_birth_country)`, then there is a sort and a table scan -- these cloud the benchmark.  That is, you are timing those things more than `EXISTS` vs `IN`.

`EXISTS` is *inherently* faster than `IN` because of the difference above.  You can see from `EXPLAIN` whether `IN` is being safely turned into `EXISTS`.  There is no need for benchmarks.

OK, so 5.7 is faster for `IN`.  Notice from `EXPLAIN` that it is using an optimization of creating a temp table.  Again, I suspect the size/structure/etc of the temp table could be contributing to whether the benchmark is fair.

With a different `LIMIT` such a temp table may be more costly than beneficial.  I suspect you found a case where the `IN` optimization beats out 'semi-join', but there could be cases where the opposite is true.

I just spotted another unfairness -- One formulation needs `INDEX(customer, quantity)`, the other needs the *opposite* order.  You have the one that benefits `IN` (store_sales_index_1).  I suspect that is why `EXISTS` did not trounce `IN` in 5.5!  Please rerun your benchmark with *both* indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's very much appreciated. You were right about the index being missing in the correct order. Once adding the correct index, EXISTS performed better / equally as IN, in all cases. The index I added, for reference, was INDEX(ss_customer_sk, ss_quantity).

Comment: On another note though - how would you approach choosing IN vs EXISTS in case NULLs are not important? You mentioned that "EXISTS is inherently faster than IN" - from your experience, is that always the case? When we should note it isn't the case and use IN when writing a query?

Comment: (I meant to recommend removing the `ss_` from the beginning of column names -- it clutters without providing useful info.)

Comment: @TomShir - In _my_ experience, `EXISTS` is never slower.  However, you uncovered a _new_ optimization for `IN`.  This is causing me to rethink my stand.  I do suspect that the outer `LIMIT` count and the number of items in the `IN` will impact whether `IN` is as efficient as your example.  That is, both of those counts could cause `IN` to be better _or_ worse than `EXISTS`.  And it will be hard to predict which.

Comment: Thank you. Will keep experimenting to find out more. By the way, the `ss_` prefix in the column names was predefined by the standard TPCDS database, which is often used for performance tests. I'm just using it :)

Comment: I asked a guru -- He says that (since 5.6) `IN` is at least as good as `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the main reason why the IN-variant performs so much better in 5.7, is that you will only look at sales that satisfies the condition on quantity and stop when you have found 1000 distinct customers.  With EXISTS, you will have to go through all sales for lots of customers that do not satisfy this condition.  Also, the query plan for IN uses a covering index on the store_sales table, and will use the PRIMARY key for look-ups into the customer tables, while the plan for EXISTS will use a secondary index.  Especially when data need to be read from disk, secondary indexes will be less efficient.

For 5.6 and later, you should prefer IN since the optimizer could then use semi-join. It is semi-join that makes it possible to reverse the order of the two tables.  (In 5.5, the tables of the outer query always need to be processed before the tables of the subquery.)  There are several alternative execution strategies for semijoin; one of them mimics the way EXISTS is executed.  Hence, as long as the optimizer gets its cost estimates right, IN should be at least as good as EXISTS.

Prior to 5.6, IN was converted to EXISTS, so both variants should perform the same.